# configure error when trying to install LASH: "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables"

Tags: linux-mint, configure

Following the LASH manual step by step, got stuck trying to run the configure script.

(LASH's dependencies are ALSA, JACK, libuuid, libxml2, GNU Readline lib, and some derivatives require GTK+2. I have all of these.)

Didn't use any options.
This is the output I get:

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... 
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

And this is config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by LASH configure 0.5.4, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.61.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/lear/lash-0.5.4/configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = Aubergine
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.13.0-24-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2042: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2098: result: /usr/bin/install -c
configure:2109: checking whether build environment is sane
configure:2152: result: yes
configure:2217: checking for gawk
configure:2233: found /usr/bin/gawk
configure:2244: result: gawk
configure:2255: checking whether make sets $(MAKE)
configure:2276: result: yes
configure:2532: checking for gcc
configure:2548: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:2559: result: gcc
configure:2797: checking for C compiler version
configure:2804: gcc --version >&5
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2807: $? = 0
configure:2814: gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.8 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.8 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libmudflap --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.8-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 
configure:2817: $? = 0
configure:2824: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:2827: $? = 4
configure:2850: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2877: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crtn.o: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:2880: $? = 1
configure:2918: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "LASH"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "lash"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.5.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "LASH 0.5.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE "lash"
| #define VERSION "0.5.4"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2925: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_env_ALSA_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_ALSA_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_ALSA_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_ALSA_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_F77_set=
ac_cv_env_F77_value=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_FFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK2_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK2_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_GTK2_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_GTK2_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_JACK_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_JACK_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_JACK_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_JACK_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_set=
ac_cv_env_PKG_CONFIG_value=
ac_cv_env_XML2_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_XML2_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_XML2_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_XML2_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_path_install='/usr/bin/install -c'
ac_cv_prog_AWK=gawk
ac_cv_prog_ac_ct_CC=gcc
ac_cv_prog_make_make_set=yes

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/lear/lash-0.5.4/missing --run aclocal-1.9 -I m4'
ALSA_CFLAGS=''
ALSA_LIBS=''
AMDEPBACKSLASH=''
AMDEP_FALSE=''
AMDEP_TRUE=''
AMTAR='${SHELL} /home/lear/lash-0.5.4/missing --run tar'
AR=''
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/lear/lash-0.5.4/missing --run autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/lear/lash-0.5.4/missing --run autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/lear/lash-0.5.4/missing --run automake-1.9'
AWK='gawk'
BUILD_PYLASH_FALSE=''
BUILD_PYLASH_TRUE=''
CC='gcc'
CCDEPMODE=''
CFLAGS=''
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXDEPMODE=''
CXXFLAGS=''
CYGPATH_W='echo'
DATE=''
DEFS=''
DEPDIR=''
ECHO='echo'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EGREP=''
EXEEXT=''
F77=''
FFLAGS=''
GREP=''
GTK2_CFLAGS=''
GTK2_LIBS=''
HAVE_GTK2_FALSE=''
HAVE_GTK2_TRUE=''
HAVE_READLINE_FALSE=''
HAVE_READLINE_TRUE=''
HAVE_TEXI2HTML_FALSE=''
HAVE_TEXI2HTML_TRUE=''
INSIDE_GNOME_COMMON_FALSE=''
INSIDE_GNOME_COMMON_TRUE='#'
INSTALL_DATA='${INSTALL} -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='${INSTALL}'
INSTALL_STRIP_PROGRAM='${SHELL} $(install_sh) -c -s'
JACK_CFLAGS=''
JACK_LIBS=''
LASH_CFLAGS=''
LASH_LIBS=''
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIBTOOL=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/lear/lash-0.5.4/missing --run makeinfo'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE='lash'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='LASH'
PACKAGE_STRING='LASH 0.5.4'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='lash'
PACKAGE_VERSION='0.5.4'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PC_REQUIRES=''
PKG_CONFIG=''
PYTHON=''
PYTHON_EXEC_PREFIX=''
PYTHON_INCLUDES=''
PYTHON_PLATFORM=''
PYTHON_PREFIX=''
PYTHON_VERSION=''
RANLIB=''
READLINE_LIBS=''
SED=''
SET_MAKE=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP=''
SWIG=''
SWIG_LIB=''
UUID_CFLAGS=''
UUID_LIBS=''
VERSION='0.5.4'
WITH_ALSA_FALSE=''
WITH_ALSA_TRUE=''
XML2_CFLAGS=''
XML2_LIBS=''
ac_ct_CC='gcc'
ac_ct_CXX=''
ac_ct_F77=''
am__fastdepCC_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCC_TRUE=''
am__fastdepCXX_FALSE=''
am__fastdepCXX_TRUE=''
am__include=''
am__leading_dot='.'
am__quote=''
am__tar='${AMTAR} chof - "$$tardir"'
am__untar='${AMTAR} xf -'
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build=''
build_alias=''
build_cpu=''
build_os=''
build_vendor=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host=''
host_alias=''
host_cpu=''
host_os=''
host_vendor=''
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
install_sh='/home/lear/lash-0.5.4/install-sh'
lash_texi2html=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
mkdir_p='mkdir -p --'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
pkgpyexecdir=''
pkgpythondir=''
prefix='NONE'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
pyexecdir=''
pythondir=''
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

#define PACKAGE_NAME "LASH"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "lash"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.5.4"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "LASH 0.5.4"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE "lash"
#define VERSION "0.5.4"

configure: exit 77
```

I noticed these lines, after which there are a bunch of dir not found error. I assume this might be the fault?

```
configure:2824: gcc -V >&5
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Afterwards it mentions failed program as 'confdefs.h', which I couldn't find anywhere.

Tried looking around for this error, seems like every time it's a different cause at a different prorgam. I tried to see if a few cases happened to solve this case, but none did.

I'm running Mint 17 Xfce.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the `libc6-dev` package installed?

Comment: No, it wasn't. 
That solved this specific problem, so thanks.
Then it fell on a different problem, missing jack1 (although I have jack2), which made me realise I'm trying to install the wrong programs tree.